# Extract out home team and away teams separated by "at" in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of Matchups in college basketball:

```
c("#34 Colorado  at  #36 California", "#31 Utah  at  #87 Stanford", 
"#26 USC  at  #112 Wash State", "#56 UCLA  at  #134 Washington", 
"#187 W Illinois  at  #116 Neb Omaha", "#222 Denver  at  #58 S Dakota St", 
"#245 IUPUI  at  #170 South Dakota", "#268 Rice  at  #208 TX El Paso", 
"#274 North Texas  at  #344 TX-San Ant", "#14 Iowa  at  #3 Purdue"
)
```

I'd like two separate vectors: one for the teams before `at` and the other for teams that appear after `at`. For ex) first vector would have `Colorado`, `Utah`, `USC`, etc and the second vector would have  `California`, `Stanford`, `Wash State`, etc.

Notice how I don't want the # rankings. I just want the team names. I've tried `str_split`ing, but doesn't work too well since the spacings are all inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` and split on "at" which will give us 2 parts of string and from every part we remove "#" followed by number and put it in a dataframe.

```
data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(string, "\\bat\\b"), 
             function(x) trimws(sub("#[0-9]+", "", x)))))


#            X1           X2
#1     Colorado   California
#2         Utah     Stanford
#3          USC   Wash State
#4         UCLA   Washington
#5    W Illinois    Neb Omaha
#6       Denver  S Dakota St
#7        IUPUI South Dakota
#8         Rice   TX El Paso
#9  North Texas   TX-San Ant
#10        Iowa       Purdue
```

---

Or using `tidyr::separate`

```
tidyr::separate(data.frame(col = trimws(gsub("#[0-9]+", "", string))),
        col, into = c("T1", "T2"), sep = "\\bat\\b")


#            T1                T2
#1     Colorado        California
#2         Utah          Stanford
#3          USC        Wash State
#4         UCLA        Washington
#5   W Illinois         Neb Omaha
#6       Denver       S Dakota St
#7        IUPUI      South Dakota
#8         Rice        TX El Paso
#9  North Texas        TX-San Ant
#10        Iowa            Purdue
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `str_extract_all()`

```r
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 text = c("#34 Colorado  at  #36 California", "#31 Utah  at  #87 Stanford", 
                          "#26 USC  at  #112 Wash State", "#56 UCLA  at  #134 Washington", 
                          "#187 W Illinois  at  #116 Neb Omaha", "#222 Denver  at  #58 S Dakota St", 
                          "#245 IUPUI  at  #170 South Dakota", "#268 Rice  at  #208 TX El Paso", 
                          "#274 North Texas  at  #344 TX-San Ant", "#14 Iowa  at  #3 Purdue")
)

library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    mutate(team_a = str_extract_all(text, "(?<=\\s).+(?=\\s+at)"),
           team_b = str_extract_all(text, "(?<=\\d\\s)[^\\d]+$"))
#>                                     text       team_a       team_b
#> 1       #34 Colorado  at  #36 California    Colorado    California
#> 2             #31 Utah  at  #87 Stanford        Utah      Stanford
#> 3           #26 USC  at  #112 Wash State         USC    Wash State
#> 4          #56 UCLA  at  #134 Washington        UCLA    Washington
#> 5    #187 W Illinois  at  #116 Neb Omaha  W Illinois     Neb Omaha
#> 6       #222 Denver  at  #58 S Dakota St      Denver   S Dakota St
#> 7      #245 IUPUI  at  #170 South Dakota       IUPUI  South Dakota
#> 8         #268 Rice  at  #208 TX El Paso        Rice    TX El Paso
#> 9  #274 North Texas  at  #344 TX-San Ant North Texas    TX-San Ant
#> 10               #14 Iowa  at  #3 Purdue        Iowa        Purdue
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R` by removing substring from the 'text' column and using `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text = trimws(gsub("#\\d+", "", gsub("\\s+at\\s+", ",", df$text))),
        header = FALSE, col.names = c("T1", "T2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#            T1            T2
#1     Colorado    California
#2         Utah      Stanford
#3          USC    Wash State
#4         UCLA    Washington
#5   W Illinois     Neb Omaha
#6       Denver   S Dakota St
#7        IUPUI  South Dakota
#8         Rice    TX El Paso
#9  North Texas    TX-San Ant
#10        Iowa        Purdue
```